# 'Unknown element' when using custom component

Tags: angular, core-ui

I recently cloned the CoreUI Admin Dashboard template and have started to modify it by adding my own custom components. Unfortunately when attempting to call the component by its selector it returns `app-suggestion-card is not a known element`.

The component was generated by running `ng g component suggestion-card` which I've double checked in `app-module.ts` that it has been added to the declarations.

```
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...APP_CONTAINERS,
    P404Component,
    P500Component,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    SuggestionCardComponent,
  ],
```

I am simply attempting to call it using `<app-suggestion-card>`. The application compiles correctly other than this.

Answer (score -1):

Your component needs to be included in the `declarations` list and the `exports` list from whichever module it is a part of,

```
declarations: [
...
SuggestionCardComponent,
],
exports: [
  SuggestionCardComponent
]
```

And the module that is using the component needs to have it listed in its `imports` list,

```
imports: [
  SuggestionCardComponent
 ]
```

Edit: Take a look at this: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules

Comment: This is not the case, based on my previous training, and the fact ```ng g component``` only declares the feature component in the ```declarations``` list. To ground truth this I implemented your suggestion and still have the same error.